# PHP MySQL Unexplained Null Values-How To Insert all Values In one Record?

Tags: php, mysql, null, html-table

I have this HTML form page:

**form1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Insert Your Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> Insert Your Name</h3>
    <form action="form1.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
       Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
    E-mail:  <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
            <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That forwards to this PHP script to handle the form:

**form1.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die ("Couldn't Connect To Server");
$db = mysql_select_db("db1", $connection)
or die ("Couldn't Select Database");
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (Name VARCHAR(20))";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (fname) VALUES ('".$_POST[fname]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (lname) VALUES ('".$_POST[lname]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (mail) VALUES ('".$_POST[mail]."')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
    echo "<TABLE BORDER = '1'>";
    echo "<TR>";
    echo "<TH>First Name</TH>";
    echo "</TR>";    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
echo "<TR>";
echo "<TD>", $row['fname'], "</TD><TD>",
$row['lname'], "</TD><TD>",
$row['mail'], "</TD>";
echo "</TR>";  
     }
    echo "</TABLE>";
    mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Now, for some reason, when I insert these values:

```
First Name: Wide
Last Name: Blade
```

I get lots of NULL values in the MySQL Table.

So my question is: How do I insert all of these values in the same record, so I don't get these NULL records in the table?

Comment: @ajreal not sure I understood the edit... explain?

Comment: @WideBlase - cut the greeting, does not help with your question

Comment: @ajreal - will do from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert adds a new record (row) into the database - you only want to execute an insert statement once.

```
INSERT INTO table1(fname, lname, mail) VALUES ($fname, $lname, $mail);
```

UPDATE: Also - you need to protect against sql injection, either by escaping input, or using prepared statements.

Comment: OK Freddie-so I changed everything to a single record.

Comment: What is this escaping input? care to refer to something good to read about it?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ explains sql injection....

this tells you how to fix: http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/47578-tip-protect-yourself-against-sql-injection.html